# Building with JDK Version `11.0.1` is not supported. Please install JDK version `1.8.0`

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I have downloaded visual studio for mac and try to start learning xamarin is iOS and Android

the problem is when I try to run the android project I got the following error

```
Building with JDK Version `11.0.1` is not supported. Please install JDK version `1.8.0`
```

knowing that I have installed java **1.8.0**, but I can not see it when i run java --version on terminal, I can only see **11.0.1**

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Microsoft's version of OpenJDK to avoid using a system installed version of Java. This is strictly used by Xamarin.Android for the MSBuild processes and not any "normal" Java development.

> Beginning with Visual Studio 15.9 and Visual Studio for Mac 7.7, Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin will move from Oracle’s JDK to a lightweight version of the OpenJDK that is intended solely for Android development:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/openjdk

> The benefits of this move are:

- You will always have an OpenJDK version that works for Android development.
- Downloading JDK 9 or 10 won’t affect the development experience.
- Significantly reduced download size and footprint.
- No more issues with 3rd party servers and installers.